# I'm addicted to em's

Tags: css

I'm addicted to 'em' as a unit of measurement with CSS, it just seems so natural to use it over pixels and plays very nicely with percentages, much more so than pixels.

Is there such a thing as a bad place to use it because after using it for several months I've yet to find a place that it didn't do what I wanted better than pixels aside from setting my outermost container width and heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can become unstuck with the EM unit of measurement if you have a load of nested elements where you're setting the size of something as ems and they have an increasing size.

For example, if you set your initial font size as 1.01em (to take from the browser/user specified defaults) and do something crazy like : `div {font-size : 1.1em;}`, and then have some html like:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>Some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The text at the third level will be 1.01 * 1.1 * 1.1 * 1.1 em, and therefore larger than you thought.  In these instances, you might choose to use the unit of measure `rem`, which is the em measurement from the root node.

In the example above, if the css was `div {font-size : 1.1rem;}` then the text at the third div level would only be 1.01 * 1.1 em.